# "Spotlight" trancparency

Tags: vb.net, transparency

I am creating a medical image application. I have two images. The first is identical to the second except that the it has a skeleton superimposed over it. I would like when the user moves the mouse over the overlaid image a spotlight area of transparency will show the image underneath. I have done this with javascript on web pages but I can't find how to do it with VB 2015. I was able to sort of make it work using 21 separate images and swapping them but it's messy and doesn't work well.

Comment: You need to use a mask and if you are using WinForms, you are in for headaches.

Comment: Draw the skeleton.  Use Graphics.SetClip(GraphicsPath) and draw the 'bottom' image.